# Has some one R444A01 modbus rtu protocol

Tags: modbus

I am looking for something like a datasheet for the R444A01 modbus rtu protocol. I want to implement a tool to read the temperature and the Humidity of this sensor.

the only thing what I could found is something like this: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/376848/datenBlatt_teil2.pdf

But to implement the tool I miss information about the modbus register definitions like Modbus address, which register stores which information and how many bytes are used.

May someone have some information about this sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting one of the reviewers from https://www.amazon.co.uk/Temperature-Humidity-humidity-temperature-External/dp/B078PHLR4T:

> Supply voltage: DC 5-40V (recommended 6.5-28V) MODBUS RTU protocol, 03
>   read command, 06 write command. Serial port baud rate: 9600 (default),
>   N, 8, 1
>
> Temperature Register Address 0x0000 (2 bytes) Humidity Register
>   Address 0x0001 (2 bytes) RS485 Address 0x0002 (2 bytes) Baud Rate
>   0x0003 (2 bytes)
>
> Baud Rate Table : 0:1200 / 1:2400 / 2:4800 / 3:9600(default) / 4:
>   19200
>
> Values returned in temperature is a SIGNED two byte value meaning that
>   a 1 in the highest bit indicates a negative temperature. Divide by 10
>   (decimal) to get the actual value
>
> Values returned in humidity is an UNSIGNED two byte value. Divide
>   by 10 (decimal) to get the actual value

Answer (score 1):

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33054683552.html shows the R444A01 modbus RTU communication protocol. I could not find a proper datasheet either.

Comment: thank you for the fast response. I will try it and will give feedback